# Django form not rendering in the html page

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and have created the form using ModelForms. First I wrote the views.py as function but once I tried to make it class the form is not rendering while rest of the tags are working. This is my `views.py` in function method

```
def company(request):
    company = Company.objects.all()
    cform = CompanyForm()
    form = CompanyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/company')
    return render(request,'company/company.html',{
        'company': company,
        'cform':cform
    })
```

This is class based `views.py`

```
class CompanyView(generic.TemplateView):
    model = 'Company'
    template_name = 'company/company.html'
```

I have updated the `urls.py` like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('form/',views.CompanyView.as_view(),name='company'),
]
```

Finally this is my html template

```
<h1>{{ company.company_name }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for company in company.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ company.company_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <h2> Company Form </h2>
        </legend>

        {{ cform.as_p }}

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and `forms.py`

```
from .models import Company

# create a ModelForm
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company_name','location','email_id')
```

When `class CompanyView(generic.DetailView):` is given I get an exception of `Exception Type: AttributeError at /company/form/ Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'`.
When its updated to `class CompanyView(generic.FormView):` the error exception is `'NoneType' object is not callable`

`class CompanyView(generic.TemplateView):` renders everything except the `{{ cform.as_p }}`

I tried many changes to the template and all but I am not able to find the error here.

Comment: Do you have any exception?

Comment: No I don't have, `{{ cform.as_p }}` is not rendering in the class menthod. Everything else is rendered properly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using class based views, you do not need the function definition as you have it above, be sure to remove it. Refer to the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms)

Try this class based definition and template:

```
class CompanyView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'company/company.html'
    form_class = CompanyForm
    success_url = '/redirect-to-somewhere/'
```

And then in your HTML, refer to only `{{ form.as_p }}`:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <h2> Company Form </h2>
        </legend>

        {{ form.as_p }}

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you for pointing it out I was able to solve it.

Comment: Happy to hear that!